# Matching FontAwesome background in icon bar

Tags: html, css, font-awesome, font-awesome-4

I'm trying to replicate this [W3 icon bar tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_icon_bar.asp) for my website, and it uses FontAwesome icons.

HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<!-- menu -->
<div class="icon-bar">
  <a href="#" class="active"><i class="fa fa-home"></i><br>Início</a>
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user"></i><br>Sobre</a>
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-list"></i><br>Serviços</a>
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-money"></i><br>Preços</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: helvetica;
    background-color: rgb(50, 50, 50);
}

/* menu */
.icon-bar {
  width: 100%; /* Full-width */
  background-color: #555; /* Dark-grey background */
  overflow: auto; /* Overflow due to float */
}

.icon-bar a {
  float: left; /* Float links side by side */
  width: 25%; /* Equal width (4 icons with 25% width each = 100%) */
  padding: 12px 0; /* Some top and bottom padding */
  transition: all 0.3s ease; /* Add transition for hover effects */
  color: white; /* White text color */
  font-size: 20px; /* Increased font size */
  text-decoration: none;
}

.icon-bar a:hover {
  background-color: #000; /* Add a hover color */
}

.active {
  background-color: #04AA6D; /* Add an active/current color */
}
/* end menu */
```

But I'm struggling with dark backgrounds in each icon, as per this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/paraibera/5xrqdc4o/3/). It seems the icon goes through the icon bar and matches the body background.

Is there a way to match the green background for the icon itself?

I noticed that it displays nicely when i remove the body background-color in CSS but I wanted to keep it.

Comment: `.icon-bar i {color: #04AA6D;}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

#### set the background of the icon `i` to transparent

```
.icon-bar i {
    background: transparent;
}
```

**Snippet Below**

```css
* {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: helvetica;
  background-color: rgb(50, 50, 50);
}

/* menu */
.icon-bar {
  width: 100%; /* Full-width */
  background-color: #555; /* Dark-grey background */
  overflow: auto; /* Overflow due to float */
}

.icon-bar a {
  float: left; /* Float links side by side */
  width: 25%; /* Equal width (5 icons with 20% width each = 100%) */
  padding: 12px 0; /* Some top and bottom padding */
  transition: all 0.3s ease; /* Add transition for hover effects */
  color: white; /* White text color */
  font-size: 20px; /* Increased font size */
  text-decoration: none;
}

.icon-bar a:hover  {
  background-color: #000; /* Add a hover color */
}

.active {
  background-color: #04AA6D; /* Add an active/current color */
}

.icon-bar i {
 background: transparent
}
/* fim menu */
```

```html
<!-- Add icon library -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<!-- menu -->
<div class="icon-bar">
  <a href="#" class="active"><i class="fa fa-home"></i><br>Início</a>
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user"></i><br>Sobre</a>
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-list"></i><br>Serviços</a>
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-money"></i><br>Preços</a>
</div>
```

#### set the properties to `i`

here

```
.active, .active i {
  background-color: #04AA6D; /* Add an active/current color */
}
```

and here

```
.icon-bar a:hover, .icon-bar a:hover i  {
  background-color: #000; /* Add a hover color */
}
```

**Snippet below**

```css
* {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: helvetica;
  background-color: rgb(50, 50, 50);
}

/* menu */
.icon-bar {
  width: 100%; /* Full-width */
  background-color: #555; /* Dark-grey background */
  overflow: auto; /* Overflow due to float */
}

.icon-bar a {
  float: left; /* Float links side by side */
  width: 25%; /* Equal width (5 icons with 20% width each = 100%) */
  padding: 12px 0; /* Some top and bottom padding */
  transition: all 0.3s ease; /* Add transition for hover effects */
  color: white; /* White text color */
  font-size: 20px; /* Increased font size */
  text-decoration: none;
}

.icon-bar a:hover, .icon-bar a:hover i  {
  background-color: #000; /* Add a hover color */
}

.active, .active i {
  background-color: #04AA6D; /* Add an active/current color */
}
/* fim menu */
```

```html
<!-- Add icon library -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<!-- menu -->
<div class="icon-bar">
  <a href="#" class="active"><i class="fa fa-home"></i><br>Início</a>
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user"></i><br>Sobre</a>
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-list"></i><br>Serviços</a>
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-money"></i><br>Preços</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this css to remove the background on the icons!

```
.icon-bar a i {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```